# Variance Minimization

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, optimization

Thanks for viewing the problem. Recently, I was calculating variance for some predesigned binary probability distribution and the variance comes out as a form of functional which includes the probability function. It is then a challenging task for me to find the optimal pdf since I have very little understandings about Functional Analysis.

\begin{align} Var[X] = 2pm^2 + (p-q)m^2[2P_{1}(3p-q)\ - \ 4pP_{1}^2 \ - \ (p-q)]\end{align}

where in the formula

\begin{align} P_1 :[-1 , 1] \rightarrow [0 , 1] \end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: what do you want to do?